# How can I calculate score from json value in laravel?

Tags: json, laravel

I have this JSON data when I saved. I have a total of 43 data inside this JSON.

```
"{"question":["1","1","1","1","1","1","1","2","2","3","3","2","2","1","3","2","1","2","3","1","2","3","3","3","2","1","2","3","1","2","3","1","2","3","1","2","3","1","2","3","1","2","3"]}
```

Then, I'm trying to calculate the score of this JSON data using this calculation. But it not calculate it because I did not get the JSON data value. I tried dd($survey_score) and it just totals up to 100 as it only assumes all value is "1".

```
$survey_score = round(((($request->question_1)+($request->question_2)+($request->question_3)+(..plus untill 43 question))/129),0) * 100;
```

So my question is how can I calculate this JSON value in my Laravel Controller? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it will work :

```
$a = '{"question":["1","1","1","1","1","1","1","2","2","3","3","2","2","1","3","2","1","2","3","1","2","3","3","3","2","1","2","3","1","2","3","1","2","3","1","2","3","1","2","3","1","2","3"]}';

$a = json_decode($a, true);

$sum = 0;
foreach($a['question'] as $key => $value){
     $sum += $value;
}

echo $sum; // 83
```

Above code has tested **[here](https://rextester.com/RCWCI36743)**

Comment: Thank you for your help! I try your code, it works!

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = '{"question":["1","1","1","1","1","1","1","2","2","3","3","2","2","1","3","2","1","2","3","1","2","3","3","3","2","1","2","3","1","2","3","1","2","3","1","2","3","1","2","3","1","2","3"]}';

$arr = json_decode($a, true);

echo array_sum($arr['question']);

Output: 83
```

Answer (score 0):

You can covert your data to collection.

```
 $scores = '{"question":["1","1","1","1","1","1","1","2","2","3","3","2","2","1","3","2","1","2","3","1","2","3","3","3","2","1","2","3","1","2","3","1","2","3","1","2","3","1","2","3","1","2","3"]}';
$arr = json_decode($scores, true);
$result = collect($arr['question'])->sum();

Output: 83
```